# Too many requests error for my newly purchased VPS

Tags: discussion, rate-limiting

I know this has been discussed before and there's an email address to address them issue, but it's been around 10 days since I sent email to team@stackexchange.com, but I didn't get any replies.

The issue is I leased a [VPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) around two weeks ago and when I want to go to any Stack Exchange sites I get the following error (I hid my IP address - tell me if it's required):

> This IP address (MyIPv4) has performed an unusually high number of
> requests and has been temporarily rate limited. If you believe this to
> be in error, please contact us at team@stackexchange.com.
>
> When contacting us, please include the following information in the
> email:
>
> Method: rate limit
>
> XID: 1749594070-HEL
>
> IP: MyIPv4
>
> X-Forwarded-For: MyIPv4
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 *Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64*
> AppleWebKit/537.36 *KHTML, like Gecko* Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
>
> Reason: Request rate.
>
> Time: Sun, 18 Dec 2022 19:39:28 GMT
>
> URL: stackoverflow.com/
>
> Browser Location: https://stackoverflow.com/

What should I do rather than emailing and waiting for the reply?

Comment: *what should I do* ... make fewer requests?

Comment: @rene I never visited this site before purchasing VPS, and I only use google chrome. The very first I visited I got this error.

Comment: Switch to a TOR browser or use a VPN to relocate your exit point away from that current ip-range you're in. I expect the continuous denial of service attacks that happens towards the SE network happen from leased or hacked VPS-es. I don't expect SE to make an exemption for one case.

Comment: @rene that's not a hacked one. That's a Hetzner Cloud VPS I purchased.

Comment: There's not anything you can do but email. But you should also know that we don't provide much if any support for VPS IPs. You'll have to accept that more than just you utilize these IPs and that you will be affected by more than just your own traffic. E.g. we completely block most AWS IPs from our servers because of the amount of abuse that came from them. Solution: don't use them to access our sites.

Comment: @animuson that reads like an answer to me ;)

Comment: Well, many other people purchased the same VPS, and got the same IP address, hence many requests. Consider buying less popular IP address and hopefully less people will be using it, and you won't get error.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars unfortunately I'm from Iran and internet sucks here, so many websites do not load properly (hanging during TLS Handshake), so I have to use VPS to do my works. That's the reason I use VPS.

Comment: @animuson isn't there any way to say the stack team to unlock my IP? As I mentioned in comments I'm from Iran and sometimes stack's website do not load properly (hanging during SSL/TLS Handshake) and cannot see the questions and answers. I mean any faster way or rather than email.

Comment: @animuson hiya, just a gentle reminder if you want to post your comment as an answer?